# Swagger authentication in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, swagger, swagger-ui

In my Azure Mobile .NET backend I want to use [Azure Mobile .NET Server Swagger](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Swagger/) . I'm looking for fast way to hide swagger UI from public access ? Is there any way to provide access only for selected users ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First a disclaimer: Even if you protect your Swagger UI from public consumption, you are not protecting your APIs from public consumption. You have to assume that everyone knows all of your routes and have the appropriate security in place to protect any requests that may come in.

That being said, there's still not a simple way to do this. [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) (the piece that adds Swagger to Web API) adds a custom `HttpMessageHandler` to the `/swagger/ui` route (as seen [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/Swashbuckle.Core/Application/HttpConfigurationExtensions.cs#L91)). If you look at the [Web API pipeline](http://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf), you can see that if you specify a custom handler, you can bypass all of the Controller selection, Auth filters, etc. This is what happens here.

Some solutions:

1. Use an app setting to conditionally call `ConfigureSwagger(config)` in debug modes only. This would prevent all `/swagger` routes from making it into production. Or you could use a staging slot and only add it there.
2. You can wrap the `SwaggerUiHandler` with something like this [Basic Auth MessageHandler](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/30/A-WebAPI-Basic-Authentication-MessageHandler). This would prompt the user for basic creds if they went to the `/swagger/ui` route. See below for my modified version of this code.

Maybe with a little more thought we can come up with a better solution -- I see a couple of issues ([here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/384) and [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/417)) in the Swashbuckle repo that indicate you're not the first one to hit this.

**Modified BasicAuthHandler (from [here](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/30/A-WebAPI-Basic-Authentication-MessageHandler)):**

*Warning: minimally tested (and be sure to change how you verify user/pass)*

```
public class BasicAuthMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private const string BasicAuthResponseHeader = "WWW-Authenticate";
    private const string BasicAuthResponseHeaderValue = "Basic";

    public BasicAuthMessageHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler)
    {
        this.InnerHandler = innerHandler;
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        AuthenticationHeaderValue authValue = request.Headers.Authorization;
        HttpResponseMessage unauthorizedResponse = request.CreateUnauthorizedResponse();

        if (authValue != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authValue.Parameter))
        {
            Credentials parsedCredentials = ParseAuthorizationHeader(authValue.Parameter);
            if (parsedCredentials != null)
            {
                // TODO: Check that the user/pass are valid
                if (parsedCredentials.Username == "user" &&
                    parsedCredentials.Password == "pass")
                {
                    // If match, pass along to the inner handler
                    return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Prompt for creds
            unauthorizedResponse.Headers.Add(BasicAuthResponseHeader, BasicAuthResponseHeaderValue);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(unauthorizedResponse);
    }

    private Credentials ParseAuthorizationHeader(string authHeader)
    {
        string[] credentials = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert
                                                        .FromBase64String(authHeader))
                                                        .Split(
                                                        new[] { ':' });
        if (credentials.Length != 2 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials[0])
            || string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials[1])) return null;
        return new Credentials()
        {
            Username = credentials[0],
            Password = credentials[1],
        };
    }
}
```

**Registering with Swagger route**

```
// Do this after calling ConfigureSwagger
ConfigureSwagger(config);

// Remove the swagger_ui route and re-add it with the wrapped handler.
var route = config.Routes["swagger_ui"];
config.Routes.Remove("swagger_ui");
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("swagger_ui", route.RouteTemplate, route.Defaults, route.Constraints, new BasicAuthMessageHandler(route.Handler));
```

Comment: if I try to remove the swagger_ui route I via config.Routes.Remove("swagger_ui") I get the following error: An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: This operation is not supported by 'HostedHttpRouteCollection'.

any idea how to modify the route?

Comment: Are you using GlobalConfiguration.Configure to set up Web API? http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/configuring-aspnet-web-api#webhost. All of our samples use OWIN Self-hosting (docs are in the same page as the previous link) and it looks like if you run through GlobalConfiguration you get a different RouteCollection type that does not support Remove. If that's what you're doing, I can investigate a bit more.

Comment: yes we're using GlobalConfiguration, but I fixed it by replacing your config.Routes.Remove("swagger_ui"); with RouteTable.Routes.Remove(RouteTable.Routes["swagger_ui"]); and now it works