# Swagger UI not working with Swashbuckle latest version

Tags: azure, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am using Swashbuckle 5.3 version in my .NET Web API with Basic Authentication (as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35877009/swagger-authentication-in-azure-app-service)). Now when I am trying to update with Swashbuckle 5.6 version, it's throwing error 'Key is not found'. 
The issue is at following code snippet. During route mapping, it's not able to find 'swagger_ui' from route collections. I tried with other different route values ( like 'swagger' , '/swagger','swagger/docs' ) but none of them is working

```
 var route = config.Routes["swagger_ui"];
        config.Routes.Remove("swagger_ui");
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("swagger_ui", route.RouteTemplate, route.Defaults, route.Constraints, new AuthMessageHandler(route.Handler));
```

Comment: That is very strange, Do you have a minimal project reproducing this issue?

Comment: I replaced 'swagger_ui'  with 'swagger_ui_shortcut' and it works :) I did change by referring this [link](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/Swashbuckle.Core/Application/HttpConfigurationExtensions.cs)

Answer (score 0):

I replaced 'swagger_ui' with 'swagger_ui_shortcut' and it works :) I did change by referring this [link] (https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/Swashbuckle.Core/Application/HttpConfigurationExtensions.cs)
But I will investigate for proper solution